# Calculate the limit of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kz^k, z \in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I calculate the limit of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kz^k, z \in (0,1)$? I only know how to show whether a given sequence converges, but I'm not sure how to apply the theorems about infinite series to calculate limits. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $(-1)^kz^k = (-z)^k$, then $S = \dfrac{1}{1- (-z)} = \dfrac{1}{1+z}$ because it is a geometric series with $|-z| = z < 1$